# How to test "loop" vs "while" loop memory usage without GC in Ruby

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection

I have  code tested in Ruby versions 2.4 and 2.7:

1.

```
    GC.disable

    while true
        ?a
    end
```

2.

```
    GC.disable
    puts ?a while true
```

3.

```
    GC.disable

    loop do
        ?a
    end
```

4.

```
    GC.disable

    loop do
        puts ?a
    end
```

Examples 1 through 4 should use all the available memory and swap because they all create string `a` in an infinite loop such that:

- GC is disabled.
- String `a` is not frozen.

But #1 doesn't consume more than a byte while it's executed. #2, #3 and #4 use as much memory as possible. On my system, they consume around 250 MB  per second or so. As expected the usage of a CPU core is 100%.

Why does #1 barely consume any memory while the others use all the available system memory in a very short time?

Comment: Things I've noticed in no particular order: on my system, code 2 consumes all available memory, too. When inspecting the instruction sequence via `ruby --dump=insns <filename>`, it seems that Ruby optimizes the literal away in code 1. It also shows that `loop` creates a block (i.e. new variable scope) whereas `while` doesn't. Adding `# frozen_string_literal: true` eliminates memory consumption for all 4.

Comment: Oops, 2 also falls in the category of 3 and 4 (kernel was writing pages to the zram, didn't notice), edited now. Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stefan is correct in his comment in that the while loop isn't creating a new scope.

Notice too the effect of the `puts` method. It is assigning a new object in memory each time it's called for the string.

```
require "benchmark/memory"

Benchmark.memory do |x|
  x.report("Test1") { puts ?a }
  x.report("Test2") { ?a }
  x.report("Test3") { puts ?a; puts ?a; puts ?a; puts ?a; puts ?a; puts ?a; puts ?a; puts ?a; puts ?a; puts ?a }
  x.report("Test4") { ?a; ?a; ?a; ?a; ?a; ?a; ?a; ?a; ?a; ?a; }

  x.compare!
end
```

Output:

```
Calculating -------------------------------------
           Test1    40.000  memsize (     0.000  retained)
                     1.000  objects (     0.000  retained)
                     1.000  strings (     0.000  retained)
           Test2    40.000  memsize (     0.000  retained)
                     1.000  objects (     0.000  retained)
                     1.000  strings (     0.000  retained)
           Test3   400.000  memsize (     0.000  retained)
                    10.000  objects (     0.000  retained)
                     1.000  strings (     0.000  retained)
           Test4    40.000  memsize (     0.000  retained)
                     1.000  objects (     0.000  retained)
                     1.000  strings (     0.000  retained)

Comparison:
           Test1:         40 allocated
           Test2:         40 allocated - same
           Test3:        400 allocated - 10.00x more
           Test4:         40 allocated - same
```